# Where is wp8 sdk after installation on Visual Studio 2012 Express

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8

I installed Visual Studio 2012 Express. Then I installed WP8 SDK.
But after installation, I cannot find WP8 option in VS 2012 express.

Welcome any comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WP8 SDK will install "Visual Studio Express for Windows Phone" as a separate install to your other Visual Studio 2012 Express product. See [MSDN for how to launch it.](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/products/visual-studio-express-for-windows-phone#product-express-phone-details)

You cannot create a WP project from your other Visual Studio Express install. For that you will need Visual Studio Professional.

See this thread in [Programmers.StackExchange](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/166716/visual-studio-2012-express-vs-professional) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new Project and then Select Windows Phone. There should be a list of possible Project types then...

Your question is not very precise